# Trouble connecting WebSocket with Broker Mosquitto

Tags: javascript, websocket, mqtt, mosquitto

so I've been trying to create a simple web page with Apache made with bootstrap from where I can send/receive publication with Mosquitto.

My issue here is that when I try to connect to the mqtt client i get this errors, i tried every combination that i found looking on guides and other stuff i founded, i either get ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED or Error 404 or CONNECTION_RESET.

> WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:9001/mqtt' failed: Error in
>   connection establishment: net::**ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED**

I tried looking up ways to fix this, so I added in /etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf:

```
#listener 8081 
#protocol websockets

#listener 8080
#protocol websockets

#port 9001
listener 9001
protocol websockets
```

My index.php file (at some point i just kept adding stuff):

```
<head >
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta charset="utf-8"> 
    <!-- MQTT Websocket -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/paho-mqtt/1.0.2/mqttws31.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/paho-mqtt/1.0.1/mqttws31.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

   <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
   var mqtt;
   var reconnectTimeout = 2000;
   var host = 'localhost';
   var port = 9001;


   function onConnect() {
       message = new Paho.MQTT.Message("Test");
       message.destinationName = 'test';
       mqtt.send(message);
   }

   function onFail() {
       console.log("fail")
   }

   function MQTTconnect() {
       mqtt = new Paho.MQTT.Client(host, port, '/mqtt', "mark");
       var options = {
           cleanSession: true,
           useSSL: false,
           timeout: 3,
           onSuccess: onConnect,
           onFailure: onFail,
        };

        mqtt.connect(options);
    }  

</script>
```

If anyone could kindly tell me if i missed something or what i have to do to make the connection work I'd gladly appreciate! I've been stuck like this for hours now.

EDIT :
I think I found the issue i think I just had to type on a terminal

```
sudo mosquitto -c /etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf
```

and leave it open to make it work.

Comment: The websocket path for mosquitto is `/mqtt` not `/ws` (you normally shouldn't set this unless you are using a custom broker)

Comment: Also why are you trying to load 2 different versions of the paho library?

Comment: yeah i was trying /ws and i left it there but now it's back to /mqtt. I guess i just copied the imports without reading really, now i'm removing the stuff that i don't need.